# Reading file that is being appended in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a legacy application that is writing results as records to some local files. We want to process these records in real-time thus we are planning to use Flink as an engine. I know that I can read text files using `StreamingExecutionEnvironment#readFile`. It seems that we need something similar to `PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY` there but this flag causes a whole file to be reprocessed on each change, what is not what we want here.

Of course, I can write my custom source that saves number of records per file in its state. But I suppose there might be some problem with such approach with checkpointing or something - my reasoning is that if that would be easy to implement reliably, it would have been already implemented in Flink.

Any tips / suggestions how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this rather easily with a custom source, so long as you are content to be reading from a single file (per source instance). You will need to use operator state and implement checkpointing. The state handling and checkpointing will look something like this:

```java
public class CheckpointedFileSource implements SourceFunction<Event>, ListCheckpointed<Long> {
    private long eventCnt = 0;

    public void run(SourceContext<Event> sourceContext) throws Exception {
        final Object lock = sourceContext.getCheckpointLock();

        // skip over previously emitted events
        ...

        while (not cancelled) {
            read event from file;

            synchronized (lock) {
                eventCnt++;
                sourceContext.collectWithTimestamp(event, timestamp);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> snapshotState(long checkpointId, long checkpointTimestamp) throws Exception {
        return Collections.singletonList(eventCnt);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(List<Long> state) throws Exception {
        for (Long s : state)
            this.eventCnt = s;
    }

}
```

For a complete example see [the checkpointed taxi ride data source](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ververica/flinktraining/exercises/datastream_java/sources/CheckpointedTaxiRideSource.java) used in the Flink training exercises. You’ll have to adapt it a bit, since it’s designed to read a static file, rather than one that is being appended to.